# Realm Swift: how to map different Realm Objects into one List<> conformed to same protocol

Tags: swift, realm

Example:

```
protocol Animal {
  @objc dynamic var name: String {get set}
  @objc dynamic var age: Int {get set}
}
class Dog: Animal {
 @objc dynamic var dogBreed: DogBreed? = nil
}
class Cat: Animal {
 @objc dynamic var catBreed: CatBreed? = nil
}
class Bird: Animal {
 @objc dynamic var birdBreed: BirdBreed? = nil
}
class Person: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var picture: NSData? = nil 
  let pets = List<Animal>()
}
```

I'm new in Realm, but I know Realm does not support polymorphism. Is there any option to solve this example?

Comment: Solve? Not exactly - Realm Lists are homogenous. Also, dont forget to add @objc before the properties you want managed by Realm. If you could provide some clarity on what you're attempting to do we may be able to come up with something.

Comment: thank you @Jay, I just want to save different Data-Models conforming to the 'Animal' protocol to Realm data base with relation one-to-many.

Comment: The problem is that *Animal* is a protocol, not a class, and not a Realm object so it cannot be managed by Realm. Because it's not a Realm object, this `let pets = List<Animal>()` doesn't work. A better bet is to have a Realm `Animal` object with a property of `@objc dynamic var animal_type = something` where `something` could be a string, or some other type. I would suggest leveraging a Realm Enum for that var which would enable you to maintain an easy-to-use enum for all of the different animals.

Comment: Hi @Jay, I've edited my example code. The problem is the the ```Cat``` class can have different properties for example cat breed, or something else, some special info about cat only. The same for dogs, birds. But all they are animals still and have characteristics of ```Animal``` class/protocol.

Comment: Meanwhile ```Person``` still have list of pets: one-to-many relation with objects of type ```Anilmal```. How it would be better to solve such case using Realm-DataBase in Swift?

Comment: Saying 'object will have different properties' means they are non-homogenous objects and they cannot be stored in the same List. Also, *class/protocol* do not get class and protocol mixed up - they are two completely independent and separate concepts and are not interchangeable. I don't really think that you're looking for a protocol here. A protocol is a 'blueprint' of how an object should look, and when it 'looks like' the protocol, it conforms to it. In you question, neither the Dog or Cat is conforming to the Animal protocol. I think you are really looking to Subclass the Animal object.